# As with requests (python 2.7) to get the image file and then using the post to send to the server

Tags: python, post, python-2.7, http-post, python-requests

As c by requests (Python 2.7) to obtain an image file, and then use the post method to send to the server?

```
file = requests.get('http://site.com/immage.jpg')
requests.post('http://site2.com/, file=somefile')
```

how to convert a `file` to `somefile`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. What type is `requests`? Why is `file=somefile` inside the string inside of a separate parameter? What do you want to post to the server, and what is going wrong when you try?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`.content` attribute](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) of the response:

```
resp = requests.get('http://site1.example.com/immage.jpg')
requests.post('http://site2.example.com/, files=dict(file=resp.content))
```

I've posted the downloaded image as [multipart-encoded POST](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-contenten/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) with the field-name `file`. It depends on the exact application you are posting to what fieldname they expect.

Answer (score 1):

ummm you save it...

```
with open("somefile.jpg","wb") as f:
     f.write(file.content)
```

Comment: not work. TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not Response

Comment: correct is:     with open("captcha.jpg","wb") as f:
        f.write(captcha.content)